# 「お前が言うなの世界」をどのように解釈すればいいのですか。

Tags: meaning, interpretation

文脈は次のとおりです。SOS団全員が孤島で夏休みの一部を過ごすように誘われました。舞台は森さんと新木さん、それぞれ孤島の主のメイドさんと執事がSOS団のみんなを最寄りの港で出迎えにきました。自家用船に乗るちょうと前のシーンです。

> (ハルヒ)「それでこそ孤島よね！半時と言わず、何時間でも行っちゃっていいわ。絶海の孤島があたしの求める状況だもの。キョン、みくるちゃん、あんたたちももっと喜びなさい。孤島には館があって、怪しい執事とメイドさんまでいるのよ。そんな島は日本中を探してもあと二つぐらいしかないに違いないわ。」
>   (キョン) 二つもねえよ。
>   (朝比奈みくる)「わ、わあ。すごいですね・・・・・楽しみだなあ」
>   (キョンの思い)　棒読みで口ごもる朝比奈さんはいいとして、本人を目の前にして「怪しい」という形容詞をつけるハルヒの口は無礼極まる。しかし言われた方もニコヤカに微笑んでいるので、もしや本当に怪しいのかもしれない。
>   まあ、怪しいのはこのシチュエーション全体であるし、怪しさにかけてはSOS団も人後に落ちないので**お前が言うなの世界**かもしれないが、何もこうまでハルヒを有頂天にさせる筋書きにならなくてもよさそうなものだ。

Comment: 「『お前が言うな』の世界」と考えてみたらいかがですか？

Comment: @Nothingatall, ちょっと変だけど、せめてこう考えて意味がなんとなく通じます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「お前が言うな」は、自分のことを棚に上げて、人を非難する人に言います。例えば、自分も遅刻したくせに、他人の遅刻を非難したときに、「お前が言うな」とその人に対して言います。お前が言うなの世界とは、そういう状況を指していると思います。

今回の例は、ハルヒが、自分たち(SOS団)も十分怪しいのに、執事とメイドに対して怪しいと言ったことが、「お前が言うな」という事で、そのような世界、状況という事です。

「お前が言う世界」は、お前が言う(you describe, you think, you say about)世界です。

Comment: True. As far as English goes, a natural translation might be "The world you talk about" or "The world you speak about"

Answer (score 4):

お前が言うな is a slangy set phrase which is loved by otaku. This phrase is so common that there's even a shortened form, おまいう/おまゆう.

- [お前が言うな/おまゆう](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/paso_omaega.htm)
- [お前が言うなって英語でなんて言うの？](http://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/13908/)

So what's "the world of お前が言うな"? As a *tsukkomi* character, the protagonist has encountered similar situations so often that he felt there were even お前が言うなの世界, just as there are the typical ミステリーの世界, the typical ファンタジーの世界 and so on. So 世界 in this context roughly means "stereotype", "typical situation" or something like that. If a member of SOS団 points out someone is bizarre, such a situation should belong to "the world of お前が言うな", because SOS団 is undoubtedly a group of bizarre people.

Answer (score 2):

「お前が言うなの世界」という表現は、「お前が言うな」という命令形の文が「世界」を修飾したものです。連体形ではない普通の文がそのまま名詞を修飾するのは例外的で、話し言葉の中で臨時的に使われることが多いです（[「の」in「お嫁さんにしたいの好き」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16020/7810)）。

- **「お前が言うな」**
  これは、「他人のことを非難している人が自分も同じようなことをしている」ということを指摘する決まり文句です。英語で言うと "Look who's talking!" ということです。
- **「世界」**‌は、ここでは「境地」「局面」という意味で使われています。英語で言うと、"world" よりも "arena, level, setting, category" の方が近いと思います。辞書にははっきりと載っていませんが、比較的よく使われる意味です。

  > 短距離走は0.1秒を争う**世界**だ。
  >
  > どのテキストエディタが最も優れているかという議論は、もはや水かけ論の**世界**だ。
  >
  > 今度の試験は難しすぎて、合格者でも2問解けるかどうかの**世界**だった。

  なお、「お前が言うな」と「世界」の関係は同格 (appositive) です。

> （怪しさにかけては……）お前が言うなの世界かもしれない
>   (when it comes to how much suspicious...) *it may be (in) a field of "look who's talking"*
>   ≈ *"it may belongs to look-who's-talking class (of problem)"*
>   ≈ *"(we) may count it as a look-who's-talking issue"*
>   ≈ *"(we) should perhaps think it on a look-who's-talking basis"*