# Does the 好き in 誰かが好き always have a romantic meaning?

Tags: words

Would for example a sentence like ルームメートが好きだけど、彼はいつも観た後にテレビをつけっぱなしだね。work to say "I like my roommate (like in a non romantic way, as a friend, buddy, etc..) but he always leaves the TV on after he watched it." work? Or would the 好き automatically give the connotation that I'd like my roommate in a romantic way? If so, what would be a better option?

Also I hope my Japanese example sentence makes sense, feel free to correct anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

好き does not necessary have a romantic meaning, but your sentence *may* leave some room for misunderstanding if there is not enough context. For safer options, see: [Non-romantic way to say you "like" someone?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68169/5010)

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but here's one way of improving your sentence:

> ルームメートはいい人だけど、いつもテレビを観た後につけっぱなしにする(ね)。

- Used いい人だ ("is a nice guy") instead of 好きだ to address your concern.
- 彼は is unnecessary and should be omitted.
- 観る and つけっぱなし share the same object (テレビを), so it should be placed before the first verb.
- (彼は)いつもテレビをつけっぱなしだ is acceptable as sloppy Japanese, but いつもテレビをつけっぱなしにする is more canonical. It's perfectly fine to say テレビがつけっぱなしだ after noticing a TV left on, though.
- ね is for light confirmation ("...huh?", "...you know?"). Do you really need it?

Comment: Thanks @naruto for answering and suggesting an improved version of my attempt. Also maybe bit unrelated question but is there a sentence ender (like ね) that conveys annoyance, frustration, etc..? Like He always let's the TV on (that's so annoying you know)

Comment: @Alex There's [やがる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4236/5010) (technically, not a particle like ね but a helping verb), but it's a quite strong expression, so use it with care.

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah I think anything that has a strong (especially negative) emotional meaning should be used with care in my opinion. 