# grammar in verb plus の間違い

Tags: grammar

- 研究室を出た。おやおやおや、追い出されたの間違いでは？

I encountered this line when watching a drama and could not understand why "追い出されたの間違い" is grammatically correct (compared to 留学したのきっかけ（×）、留学したきっかけ（〇）、留学のきっかけ（〇）). I wonder why it is not "追い出されたという間違いでは？" or "追い出されたのを間違ったのでは？".

A Japanese friend of mine gave me a few more examples. Now I am convinced that it is a natural expression, but I still don't understand the underlying grammar. Could you help me figure it out?

- Aさんが断ったのは、Aさん自身の本心からではなく、Bさんに脅迫されたの間違いでは。
  →（Aさんが否定したのは、Aさん自身の本心からではなく）Bさんに脅迫されたの間違いでは。
- Bさんは病気で死んだのではなく、本当は医者に殺されたの間違いでは？
  →（実際には、医者に）殺されたの間違いでは？
- Cさんが会社を退職したのは、仕事が自分に適していないからではなく、辞めるように上司から追い込まれたからの間違いでは。
  →本当は、上司から追い込まれたの間違いでは？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, ～の間違い (lit. "mistake/typo/etc of ～") is used with a **noun** like this:

- PS4と言いましたが、PS5の間違いです。
  I said PS4, but I meant PS5.
- この漢字は何の間違いですか？
  What is this kanji a typo for?
- これは何かの間違いだ！ 私は悪くない！
  This must be some kind of mistake! I'm not to blame!

You can see の is simply linking two nouns in these examples.

But this can be used with a longer expression enclosed in quotes. This is because you can enclose a long phrase in quotes and treat it as a long noun.

- 「PS4が欲しい」と言いましたが、「PS5が欲しい」の間違いです。
  I said "I want a PS4", but I meant "I want a PS5".

Furtheremore, brackets can be safely omitted when there is no risk of confusion.

- PS4が欲しいと言いましたが、PS5が欲しいの間違いです。
  I said *I want a PS4*, but I meant *I want a PS5*.

So when you encounter a sentence like this, try thinking the phrase before と is implicitly enclosed in brackets and there is a long "noun" there.

Related:

- [が following an i-adj](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62976/5010)
- [「の」in「お嫁さんにしたいの好き」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16020/5010)
- [Direct and indirect quotes](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30584/5010)